# Track Finger Touch on UIButton and execute it's action

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view with several UIButton instances. Now I'd like that the user can trigger als button when he wishes over it with a long touch. So he can either touch one button or wishe over several buttons. Therefore all button actions of the touched buttons should be executed.

Here's a photo (buttons with red background color and black border):
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Best regards from Bavaria,
Chris

Comment: I have no idea what the question is. :(

Comment: Oh I'm sorry - Example: User wishes horizontally over the screen. The resultat should be that the whole line of buttons should be executed. Clear?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think 'wish' means what you think it does - it means to hope for something, or to imagine, or deeply desire, something good happening, maybe by way of asking Djinn or other spirits for help achieving this. What exactly is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question right, what you need with your grid of buttons is [UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can add the same recognizer to every instance of `UIButton` and handle all its states `(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan, UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged, UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)`.

If you want certain delay in detection (like `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`), you can trigger timer and check if finger is still inside the UIButton's frame.

Comment: +1 just for decoding the question